# Unable to access to WCF hosted in a windows service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a very weird problem with a 3 tiers client/server application with WCF.

First, I have a service windows which host WCF services in basicHttpBinding. This is the server app.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="Business.BSServiceManagement" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehave">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:35001"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address="/Clients" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Clients" contract="Contracts.BusinessFacade.IBFClientManagement"/>
                <endpoint address="/Users" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Users" contract="Contracts.BusinessFacade.IBFUserManagement"/>
                <endpoint address="/Licences" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Licences" contract="Contracts.BusinessFacade.IBFLicenceManagement"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="myServiceBehave">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This service is deployed on a server in DMZ and I have access from my computer (in firefox, if I put service address with port number)

Secondly, I have a client application made with winforms which consume the service with ChannelFactory.

This is the client app.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.128.1:35001/Clients" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Clients" contract="Contracts.BusinessFacade.IBFClientManagement"/>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.128.1:35001/Users" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Users" contract="Contracts.BusinessFacade.IBFUserManagement"/>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.128.1:35001/Licences" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Licences" contract="Contracts.BusinessFacade.IBFLicenceManagement"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I debug client application, all works perfectly. So I've made a installer project to deploy application on several computers but when I execute exe of application (installed or directly in bin/release), I have an error message like this :

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.128.1:35001/Users...
```

The inner exception says:

> Unable to connect to the remote server

I tried adding mex endpoint, change port number, check server and client computer firewall, I don't understand where is the problem.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT 1 :**

After several tests I have the same problem in release exe but not in debug exe.

If I execute the debug exe all works fine but the release exe return the error message.

Comment: Trying to understand your debugging config.  Your baseAddress node is `localhost` is that service running locally on your development machine too?

Comment: No, I installed the service on another computer in DMZ and I execute only the client on debug on my machine and it works perfectly. But when I install the client on my machine, it doesn't work

Comment: VS is usually running as administrator, what if you execute your client as  admin?  Did you add firewall settings for the client exe?

Comment: @leetibbett VS does not usually run as administrator.

Comment: Mine always has, even on my work domain where everything is restricted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Service.

Make sure that the Service is Started and running.

Once you start the Service, browse URL(eg: localhost:8080/example), just to make sure Service is running fine.

When you add Service Reference to your client Application, it automatically generates endpoints in app.config file.

When you added Installer to client project, make sure that it is builds Successfully.

When you install it, it should work for you.

Comment: All your points are OK, but I have not add Service Reference in my client application, I use ChannelFactory

Comment: Define <endpoint address> inside <Services> in Service Config file.

In client Application, define endpoint address in class, rather than config file.

ex:
 EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:1212/example");
 factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMyService>(ctx,binding,address);

Comment: @venkk `DuplexChannelFactory`? Is this a duplex-contract?

Comment: No it's a request-reply contract with a simple channelFactory. I tried yesterday to make another win form client application with service reference and same problem, ok in debug and not ok in release